# The getClass() method returns other class

Tags: java, oop

I have an unexpected and confusing issue with the instance comparing.

So, by order:

I try to compare two instance of the same class and override the `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods:

```java
public class AdminUser {
.............
  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj){
            return true;
        }

        if(obj == null){
            return false;
        }

        Class c1 = obj.getClass(); //-----------{1}
        Class c2 = this.getClass(); //----------{2}


        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()){
            return false;
        }

        AdminUser other = (AdminUser)obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.username, other.username) &&
                Objects.equals(this.username, other.username) &&
                Objects.equals(this.username, other.username);
    }
}
```

- The method, from where I compare:

```java
public class AdminCRUD extends BaseWithPerformanceTest {
    private void assertIfUserExist(AdminUser cau) {
        AdminUser createdUser = createUserForm.getUserFromForm();  //----{3}
        if(!cau.equals(createdUser)){
            saveScreenshot("Users_dont_match");
        }
    }
}
```

- The instance where I take `AdminUser` (**{3}**):

```java
public class UsersPage extends TopBarConsoleMenu {
..................
    public class CreateUserForm extends BaseForm {
        public AdminUser getUserFromForm() {
            ......................

            return new AdminUser(){{
                setEmail(ACTUAL_EMAIL);
                setName(ACTUAL_NAME);
                setUsername(ACTUAL_USER_NAME);
                setUserType(EnumUtils.getEnumByMethodName(AdminUserType.class, "getAddUserDropDownValue", ACTUAL_USER_TYPE));
                setRegion(EnumUtils.getEnumByMethodName(AdminRegion.class, "getDropdownValue", ACTUAL_REGION));
            }};
        }
    }
}
```

## So the issue:

(please see `AdminUser` class)

- In the point **{1}**, `c1` variable got the `pages.admin.UsersPage$CreateUserForm$1` instance!
- In the point **{2}** `c2` variable as expected `utils.data.admin.AdminUser$1`

Except other - the `obj` instance, actually contains correct instance! - After boxing `AdminUser other = (AdminUser)obj;` I can get any correct data from the `other` variable - there are really `AdminUser` instance!

What are happens?

Comment: By using the `{{`-"trick" (called double brace initialization) you're actually implementing an anonymous subclass of `AdminUser`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer thanks, where I can research the mechanism of this "trick" to understanding why it happens? Or could you can explain the issue in the answer?

Comment: There's a link to another question on top of your question, it has tons of details.

Comment: How can I know this issue occurred by "Double Brace initialization"? Why someone degrees my question? This question isn't duplicate.

Comment: You asked "what happened". What happened is that you created a subclass of `AdminUser` via the double-brace initialization and therefore comparing the `getClass()` return value will not be the same as a "normal" `new AdminUser` and therefore your `equals()` method will return `false`. The duplicate explains what the double-brace initialization really is and really does and why the you get a different return value.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks a lot. I understand now how it works and why it is filed. I do not understand why my question was decreased.